# What are these IP enabled lightbulbs doing on my network?

Tags: wireless-networking

I've just plugged in five of these awesome [LIFX](http://lifx.co/) IP enabled lightbulbs to my home network, and my Internet speed in the house has noticeably dropped.  So my question is this:

How can I find out what these lightbulbs are up to, what are they sending and receiving and why would this traffic slowdown my LAN so much?

I am using OS X if that helps for tool suggestions.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you connect your OS X machine to a wired connection instead of wireless, do you still see the slowdown?  It might be a problem with the lightbulbs messing up your wireless network rather than them actually sending any data.

Comment: It does seem that the network has slowed down, regardless of whether the machine is connected wirelessly or connected to the router using a wired connection.

Answer (score 2):

I can only point out several approaches. The most likely would be to use [wireshark to sniff packets from other WLAN devices](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN), assuming your wireless NIC supports monitor mode. This is simplest if any network encryption is temporarily disabled.

If you are running a router such as OpenWRT/Tomato/DD-WRT, you might be able to run wireshark (or at least tcpdump) directly through the router without much hassle. Otherwise, depending on your router you might be able to gain a limited command-line access via telnet or ssh.

Since you say the physical network is also affected, I think it is safe to rule out the 802.15.4 mesh network bulbs (for example WiFi interference) and focus on the master bulb linking the mesh network to the WiFi network. Does the problem still occur if the control device (computer software, phone) is offline or disabled? Going out on a limb, possibly the bulb is flooding you network with ARP packets. etc...